# Circuit Board on Grogu's Rondel

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In Mandalorian Season 3 episode 4 we see the armorer present Grogu with a Baskar rondel. When the armorer is making the piece, she appears to solder some circuitry to the back of it. Do we know what this circuitry is for?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or two, please?